# Is there a way to "disable" the primary constructor or force the user to always use a secondary constructor?

Tags: kotlin

Example:

```
data class Car (
    val type: TypeEnum,
    val brand: BrandEnum,
    val modelNumber: Int) 
{
    constructor(val type: TypeEnum, 
                val brand: BrandEnum,
                val input: String) : this (
        type,
        brand,
        Valdidator.validateModelNumber(input)
    )
}
```

In the code above, the method validateModelNumber() validates a raw input and throws an exception if the model number has an invalid format. I want to force the user to use this constructor every time he/she wants to make a Car object.

Essentially: I want to make sure that no invalid Car object can exist, while still making the code as immutable as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `init` block instead. Something like this

```
data class Car (
    val type: TypeEnum,
    val brand: BrandEnum,
    val modelNumber: Int)
{
    init {
        Valdidator.validateModelNumber(input)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an `init` block for validation (as per another answer) can work well if it only needs the parameters/properties specified in the primary constructor.  However, there are other approaches.

If you don't want the primary constructor to be used by other code, you can make it `private`, by changing:

```
data class Car(
```

to:

```
data class Car private constructor(
```

You could then leave a public secondary constructor for other classes to use, as in the question.  However, that's still a bit limiting, as you can't do any serious processing before calling the primary constructor.

So the usual pattern is to **have a private constructor and factory methods in the companion object**.  This is much more flexible: you can do any amount of processing before and after calling the actual constructor; you can even return cached instances, subclass instances, etc.

You can make those *look* like constructors by implementing them as `operator fun invoke()` with suitable parameters.  In this case, that could look like:

```
data class Car private constructor(
    val type: TypeEnum,
    val brand: BrandEnum,
    val modelNumber: Int) 
{
    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(type: TypeEnum, brand: BrandEnum, input: String)
            = Car(type, brand, Validator.validateModelNumber(input))
    }
}
```

You could then create instances with e.g.:

```
Car(TypeEnum.SPORTS, BrandEnum.ASTON_MARTIN, "DB5")
```

looking just like an ordinary constructor.